# Xcode 11.4 font smoothing on non-retina displays

Tags: fonts, smoothing, xcode11.4

I found that Xcode 11.4 not smooth fonts as Xcode 11.3. Please see attached screenshot.

I tried any kind of **AppleFontSmoothing** values, but it does not effect on Xcode 11.4

[image]

Does anybody know how to smooth fonts in Xcode 11.4?

Comment: Glad someone else is seeing this. I thought I was going crazy. Running into the same thing.

Comment: Any idea how to fix this? I have just updated and it's killing me I tried `defaults write -g CGFontRenderingFontSmoothingDisabled -bool true` with no success

Comment: Same here, very annoying.. Any updates on this? Did you find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately Xcode 11.4.1 doesn't fix this.

Comment: I've reported a bug, hopefully they will fix this soon.

Comment: Good idea, I did so too

Comment: I've heard back on my bug report that they're looking into it.